# Track dirty properties with annotations in Java?

Tags: java, enums, annotations

I have a problem I'm trying to work through. I have some model objects which I'd like to track if their properties change. Because of the usage pattern of these models, I'd prefer the tracking to be self-contained such that the following works:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setName = "name";
List<StudentProperties> changedProperties = student.getChangedProperties();
//changedProperties = { StudentProperties.name }
```

My first instinct was to create an internal hashmap and property enum then track changes by modifying the setters to update hashmap. I'm not a fan because it's not generic, hence I can't use one implementation for all my models.

Is there a clean solution along the lines of this:

```
@TrackChanges
public class Student implements Trackable {
    @Track
    private String name;

    public List<StudentProperties> getChangedProperties() {
        //somehow return changed properties
    }
}
```

Where via the annotations a properties enum is created, along with the map containing the properties which can be returned by getChangedProperties().

I'm open to using the observable pattern, however I'm not sure how that will work with the clients of the model (will I have to force them to also follow the observer pattern before they can use my model? Sounds intrusive and hence I'm not in favor of it).

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Java SE? If not, you could use [interceptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhjx.html).

Comment: I'm using EE, so I'll take a look at interceptors now

Comment: It requires all clients add the interceptor to the beans.xml file. If I can make it self-contained then that would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a base class called AValueObject which contains a DirtyTracker property that handles this: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-util#dirtytracker

I have also created an AspectJ aspect that handles the PropertyChangeSupport event firing for you: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-aspects#propertychangesupportedaspect

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this solution](http://yakafokon.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/beans-binding-jsr-295-with-pojo-and-aop) based on Aspect (second part of article) and `PropertyChangeSupport`. Its clean and generic

You can easily adapt it to limit the tracking for the properties that are annotated by @Track

http://yakafokon.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/beans-binding-jsr-295-with-pojo-and-aop